# Filter data if it exists in an other model?

Tags: django

```
class WPArticle(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    source = models.URLField() #article source 
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    mtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=True)
    post_tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class WPSendRecord(models.Model):
    wpconf = models.ForeignKey(WPConf)
    wparticle = models.ForeignKey(WPArticle)
    ctime = models.TimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.wparticle.title
```

I want to query out all the WPArticle which not in WPSendRecord? How to write the code?

Comment: Your posts would be easier to read if you use four-space indents rather than tabs -- I made the edit for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) QuerySet method:

```
 articles = WPArticle.objects.exclude(wpsendrecord__isnull=True)
```

Comment: All calls to *exclude* methods in django are considered a vulnerability for the portability and maintainability of the code. It is better to be explicit, if you ask me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, why is it less portable or maintainable?

Comment: Hi Timmy. Maybe I've overstated my case a bit. I've read in twoscoops of django that calling fields explicitly is easier when you have to debug after you have changed your models. That was more in the case of using `exclude` or `fields` in forms.py.